# Migrating NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to AppGroup causes CloudKit to re sync and create duplicate objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I have a CoreData store using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer within the app. When I migrate it to the AppGroup it thinks that it hasn't performed a sync before so re syncs all `CKRecords` down to the database, which then means there are duplicate records of all objects. Is there anyway to mark the migrated store as synced with the latest change token so that it doesn't perform this fresh pull?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to implement something custom in the end to remove the duplicates